# How do I save Parent -Child using EntityFramework 4?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF4 and I have a situation where I need to insert a parent child into the database using sql server 2008.
When Saving a customer I would like to save their addresses as well.

I have as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname{ get; set; }
  public List<Address> AddressList { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
  public string StreetName { get; set; }
  public string  City { get; set; }
}

public int SaveCustomer(CustomerDto customer)
{
   //TODO NEED TO BE MODIFIED
        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {

           var entityCustomer = customer.ToEntityCustomer();

           var state = entityCustomer.CustomerID > 0 ? State.Modified : State.Added;

           ctx.Customers.Attach(entityCustomer);

           ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entityCustomer , EFStateUtil.GetState(state));

           var result = ctx.SaveChanges();
           return result;
        }
    }
```

How do I modify my code to save both the customer and addresses at the same time.
Will it be one trip to the server?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to do it for each and every Address object as well:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext()) {
    var entityCustomer = customer.ToEntityCustomer();
    var state = entityCollectionGroup.CollectionGroupID > 0 
        ? State.Modified : State.Added;
    ctx.Customers.Attach(entityCustomer);
    ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entityCustomer, 
            EFStateUtil.GetState(state));

    foreach(address in entityCustomer.AddressList) {
        var addressState = // Your logic to figure out the state...
        ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(address, addressState);    
    }

    var result = ctx.SaveChanges();
    return result;
}
```

And yes it's going to be only one trip to the database to save them all as per calling SaveChanges (Unit Of Work Pattern)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key" .Not sure why I get this.It's a new object if you like

Comment: When you attach an object to the context, not only that object (e.g. Customer) but the whole graph (e.g. AddressList) would be also attached. Now, if any of those objects already exist in the cache you'll get that exception. I'm guessing that the code you are showing is not the whole story, you should have retrieved some addresses at some point? If so, then *ApplyCurrentValues* method would be a better choice than *ChangeObjectState*.

Comment: Hi,really stuck with this one.I cannot make it work.I have written this noddy project just to see if i can save it.Well the scenario I have is that a user retrieves a customer,adds some addresses and modifies some.Then the method does not like it. How do I use ApplyCurrentValues?How does it distinguish between a new and old child object or parent?If I were to upload this noddy project somewhere would somebody have a quick look.It might take somebody with EF knowledge a couple mins to see whats wrong

Comment: Of course. Just let me know where I can find it and I'll fix it for you :)

Comment: http://cid-9db5ae91a2948485.office.live.com/browse.aspx/PublicFolder?uc=1 Morteza I will be very very grateful.I have uploaded this noddy project to the link above.Created script to create db with 2 tables .THANKS

Comment: Hi,I have a slight feeling that I am always creating a new entity and therefore crashing.I hope you dont have to retrieve an object first before updating .I have posted that code

Comment: I've uploaded the updated version of this project at the following address: 
http://cid-31fdfaaf183abb01.office.live.com/browse.aspx/.Documents
It saves without fetch the objects and also handle both existing and new customers.